# using minipar parser output

Tags: nlp

how to use minipar parser output to extract features like subject , object ,verb, tense etc to be use for english text to ASL conversion project

Comment: Could you describe the ASL conversion that you want to do in more detail?

Comment: i am basically focusing on the idea that asl glosses follow subject - object - verb order and also i want to add rules for adjectives adverb etc like if the adjective specifies a color then it should precede the noun else after the noun and like wise

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to use Minipar? Not only is Minipar a rather ancient parser, but it also comes with a restrictive non-commercial use only license. If you just need a fast dependency parser, the MaltParser (http://maltparser.org/) is probably a better choice.

Comment: i am developing it for windows based systems and after going through a no. of parsers i am able to develop an interface between minipar and dotnet framework, so i'll stick to it, but i could not find a documentation for minipar , anyways thanks for your suggestion but maltparser is better if working with linux as i can figure out, please suggest something else, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Predicate-Argument Extractor (PAX)](http://www.semanticsoftware.info/pax), a GATE component to extract (subject, predicate, object) triples from the output of several parsers, including RASP, SUPPLE, MiniPar, Stanford, and MuNPEx.

Comment: i appreciate your solution but sorry i didnt mentioned i'm working with dotnet and as i could figure out gate supports java